# Prove a functional to be differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Consider the functional $I:C[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$I(x)=\int_{b}^{a}x(t)dt.$$
Prove that $I$ is differentiable and find its derivative at $x_0\in C[a,b]$.

The answer just says that it suffices to prove that I is a bounded linear operator. May I know  if "bounded linear operator" is a sufficient condition to be "differentiable"?

Also, can anyone work out the latter part of the question, to find the derivative of $I$ at $x_0$?

I appreciate your help so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, one can show that the derivative of a bounded linear operator $T$ is $T$ itself. This makes sense intuitively, as the derivative of $f$ is supposed to be the best possible bounded linear approximation to $f$. This follows straight from the definition given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition